# Automatically finding bugs in software performance tests?

Tags: r, performance, testing, statistics

I'm running a suite of some 2000+ performance tests on our software for every code change that someone makes (and for each test I collect 5 to 10 samples). I have a history of performance results for thousands of code changes.

When someone makes a code change that causes the test to run slower, I want to be told as soon as possible (though I can wait for results from another 1 or 2 code changes).

That's the gist of the problem.

There is some natural variance in these tests, and we will see occasional spikes that are just noise, maybe because some background process on the computer was doing something that caused the test to run slower this time. I do NOT want to be notified when the test ran slower for such reasons. I understand there will still be some type I error, but I want to minimize it.

Almost all code changes have no real effect on performance, and those that do usually effect a subset specific tests.

But because essentially any code change throughout our history can have changed mean/standard deviation/whatever, using that history seems precarious.

But my problem seems like one that can't be completely unique. What options do I have?

[This is a graph of how one of the tests performs over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2olMe.png). The y axis is represents time the test took (lower is better), and the x axis is each of our code changes over time from oldest to newest. That big drop early on should be called out as a real improvement, and when it goes back up, that was a real loss. Likewise towards the end of the graph, that was a real loss, followed by a real gain. All the other blips should NOT be called out.

[Here's another one where the history is mostly all just noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4sdM.png)

I've asked this question in multiple places, but have never gotten any real answers. I will be writing all of the analysis, and I'm willing to use any tool, do any research, and learn any statistical methods that will help me. This can't be a unique problem. So how to people handle it (other than manually looking through results)?

Comment: Very interesting question: but I think that this is primarily a statistics question (perhaps migrate to Cross Validated?). You may find the literature on statistical process control helpful. But, the nature of a speed change due to code is probably going to mean, big, sudden changes. These are relatively easy to detect as noted below.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more about statistics than programming. Might be migrated to Cross Validated.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can try to decrease amount of noise. You can measure time in such a way that background processes do not affect your measurement (unix time)

You would like to see if there is overall trend in your performance measure that indicates decrease in performance. If you look at it as a signal, you can apply low-pass filter (which can be simply approximated by taking k previous samples and averaging). Then use some simple threshold. This is quite simple, but I think should work, because as @nograpes wrote it is often the case that drops in performance are big.

If it doesn't work you can look at it as the problem of "trend detection". So basically the question is "is there significant trend in the time series". This is a machine learning problem/statistics problem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trend_estimation . So you could get N previous samples, try to fit ARMA (http://www.nek.lu.se/nekkfr/d-kurs/Ch4NEWunivariate.pdf) and see if the slope is positive with some threshold. However I do not know much of this method so it is just an idea :)

Comment: + Yes, but I would first log-transform the data, then do the low-pass filter. Then the threshold should be about the same whether the amount of time is small or large.